# Template 10 and netstandard 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, template10, .net-standard-2.0

I wonder if template 10 is compatible with netstandard2.0. I have a very simple library listed below:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TransactionModel
{
    public class MyTransaction
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid TransactionId { get; set; }
        public string BankID { get; set; }
        public string MerchantID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public string TransactionDescription { get; set; }
        public float TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public string TransactionComments { get; set; }

    }
    public class TransactionContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyTransaction> transactionBatch { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionBuilder)
        {
            optionBuilder.UseSqlite("Data source=transactions.db");
        }
    }
}
```

This library csproj file listed below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!--<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>-->
        <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
        <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.entityframeworkcore.Sqlite" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have installed package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and then add-migration to scaffold the database successfully.

But when I tried to make reference to TransactionModel, the compiler generated a bunch of errors, but I think this is the main error:
" Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file.."

[image]

I have attached a image of my vs2017 solution. I have written no code on T10 yet, I have just created T10 template, made reference to my library and vs2017 has generated the errors. If I use UWP, I did not get such error...

So my question is whether it is possible to use T10 with EntityFrameworkCore and netstandard2.0? Is there a way to go around the error?

[image]

Comment: correct it isn't compat., #soon when 10.2 releases, which is heavily in refactor development.  But you don't need .netstandard 2 to use sqlite in uwp...  if you are merely using EFCore previous versions work.

Comment: You can check out the current rev of Template 10 at http://aka.ms/template10 and see for yourself. The next version is imminent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create a dependency FROM a .NET Core project ON the Template 10 library because the Template 10 library is a Universal Windows Library. This is true with the current version of Template 10. This will also be true with the next version of Template 10. Why? Because Template 10 is a library built to enhance UWP application development, and, as a result, requires the Windows namespace which, as you know, is not part of .NET Standard. How could it be? The Windows namespace could never be cross-platform. That being said, the fundamental interfaces of Windows 10 (new version) are not derived from Prism.Core which is a .NET Standard library. This means the navigation interfaces and MVVM classes are all external and can be inherited side-stepping Template 10. This answers your question, I hope you understand the technical reasons things are as they are.

Comment: Nixon: Got it. Thanks! Now if I want to use SQLite with template 10 what should I do? Do you have  or know a sample project for my reference? Template 10 should be able to be used with an EntityFramework? If not, how do we persist data in Template 10?